Is coconut oil the most saturated plant-based oil?
Looking through the oils that can be used to make soaps on LyeCalc.com, I saw that coconut oil has a very high saturated fat content: 77%! Cow butterfat is comprised of only 53% saturated fat.
Is coconut oil the most saturated plant-based oil?

Yes, coconut oil is famous for being one of the most saturated plant based oils, but it is NOT the most saturated plant based oil. Palm oil or Palm kernel oil has even more saturated fat content that makes it the most saturated plant based oil. Palm kernel oil contains around 80-85% saturated fat. This is why its consumption is reduced in the food industry but still used in some low income countries due its price.
